# Can Excel Show the image if it is linked via an url?

Tags: excel, url

I have this excel document where there are many links to images in .pgn , like this 
for example :

> =@image("https://itemization.info/icons/inv_hammer_21.png")

I would like excel to show the actual image and not this error message "##".

Is there any way i can do that? Any add-ins possibly?

here is the url or document https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXJpasqqodeq9B4jeUZDP9khFQf5QocyMby6moydJWk/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true#

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/940861/how-can-i-display-a-url-as-an-image-in-an-excel-cell

Comment: the answer in the link did not work for me

Comment: means.. d u get any error? is the VBA call successful? any screenshot ?

Comment: everything when smooth i didn't get any errors, i ran the macro like i was suppose to but then nothing happened